# javaws crashes, error in ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Tags: 11.10, java

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit client as Dom0 and Xen.
I am having problems getting java up and running.
Java itself seems to work fine, however I get strange errors, for example when I start javaws.
I tried different versions and always get the same errors.

I tried openjdk 1.6 and 1.7 as well as sunjava6 and 7.
I alway get an error in the same lib

All other applications are working fine, so it seems ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is working fine.

Any hints what could be wrong?

```
Ubuntu01:~$ javaws

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007f4e74c5ad10, pid=7974, tid=139974945277696
#
# JRE version: 6.0_23-b23
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressedoops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.11pre
# Distribution: Ubuntu 11.10, package 6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x14d10]  _dl_make_stack_executable+0x2b70
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/r/hs_err_pid7974.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after several tries I could fix the issue myself. 
What worked for me was to uninstall all openjava6 and dependencies via dpkg.
That left me without javaws and the plugins.
So I installed sunjava7 64 Bit as described here 
http://brunoreis.com/tech/intalling-java-ubuntu-natty/

Now everything is working fine for me.